# K Means Clustering: function to update the centroid of each cluster and choose color

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

This is an excerpt from an example on K Means Clustering that I'm going through. Can someone help me understand what's happening in the last two lines, please?

Specifically:

1. What is `class_of_points = compare_to_first_center > compare_to_second_center` doing? Is it just returning a boolean?
2. Also in the next line what is `colors_map[class_of_points + 1 - 1]` doing?

Thanks in advance, guys.

```
import random # library for random number generation
import numpy as np # library for vectorized computation
import pandas as pd # library to process data as dataframes

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

# data
x1 = [-4.9, -3.5, 0, -4.5, -3, -1, -1.2, -4.5, -1.5, -4.5, -1, -2, -2.5, -2, -1.5, 4, 1.8, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 2.25, 1, 0, 1, 2.5, 5, 2.8, 2, 2]
x2 = [-3.5, -4, -3.5, -3, -2.9, -3, -2.6, -2.1, 0, -0.5, -0.8, -0.8, -1.5, -1.75, -1.75, 0, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 6, 6.5]

#Define a function that updates the centroid of each cluster

colors_map = np.array(['b', 'r'])
def assign_members(x1, x2, centers):

    compare_to_first_center = np.sqrt(np.square(np.array(x1) - centers[0][0]) + np.square(np.array(x2) - centers[0][1]))
    compare_to_second_center = np.sqrt(np.square(np.array(x1) - centers[1][0]) + np.square(np.array(x2) - centers[1][1]))
    class_of_points = compare_to_first_center > compare_to_second_center
    colors = colors_map[class_of_points + 1 - 1]
    return colors, class_of_points
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compare_to_first_center` is the distance of all points to `centers[0]` and similarly, `compare_to_second_center` is the distance of all points to `centers[1]`. Now, `class_of_points` is a boolean array of same size as your points, stating wether each point is closer to `center[0]` or `centers[1]`. If `class_of_points[i]` is `True`, `point[i]` in your data is closer to `centers[0]`.

`colors = colors_map[class_of_points + 1 - 1]` assigns color `b` or `r` to points, `b` if they are closer to `centers[1]` and `r` for `centers[0]`. Note that, in order to convert a boolean mask `class_of_points` to index array, they add 1 and subtract 1 so that the output converts `False` as `0` and `True` to 1, which makes them indices. An example is:

```
np.array([True, False, True])+1-1
```

is the same as

```
[1, 0, 1]
```

Alternatively, you could simply replace it with:

```
colors = colors_map[class_of_points + 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that two lists of centers are given. This code is going to compute the euclidean distance for each point to each center point and assigns the blue color to those are closer to a center point in `centers[0][:]` and red color to points closer to center points in `centers[1][:]`.

```py
def assign_members(x1, x2, centers):

    # In the following two lines, the eucledean distances are being calculated
    compare_to_first_center = np.sqrt(np.square(np.array(x1) - centers[0][0]) + np.square(np.array(x2) - centers[0][1]))
    compare_to_second_center = np.sqrt(np.square(np.array(x1) - centers[1][0]) + np.square(np.array(x2) - centers[1][1]))

    # Check which center is closer to each point
    # So class_of_points is a binary arary specifies the class number
    class_of_points = compare_to_first_center > compare_to_second_center

    # Depending on the class number (i.e. 0 or 1) it chooses the colour (blue or red)
    colors = colors_map[class_of_points + 1 - 1]
    return colors, class_of_points
```